# BJT problem. Are my calculations correct?

Tags: bjt

[image]

\$\beta = 100\$, Transistor Q1 is PNP and Q2 is NPN. Trying to find \$V_1, V_2, V_3, V_4\$, and \$V_5\$. I assumed active mode for both.

\$\beta = 100\$
\$V_{BE} = 0.7 \mathrm{V}\$

Then
$$
\alpha = \frac{\beta}{\beta + 1} = \frac{100}{101} = 0.99  
$$
and
$$
I_{B1} = (1 – \alpha)I_{E1} \iff I_{B1} = 0.01I_{E1}
$$
Now,
$$
\frac{V_1}{100000} = \frac{0.01(3 - V_2)}{9100} = 3.2967 \cdot 10^{-6} - 1.0989 \cdot 10^{-6}V_2
$$
Then
$$
\frac{(V_2  - 0.7)}{100000} = 3.2967 \cdot 10^{-6} - 1.0989 \cdot 10^{-6}V_2
$$
$$
V_2 – 0.7 = 0.3296703297 - 0.1098901099V_2 \iff 1.1098901099V_2 = 1.02967033
$$
thus
$$
V_2 = 0.9277227723 \mathrm{V}
$$
and
$$
V_1 = V_2 – 0.7 = 0.9277227723 – 0.7 = 0.2277227723 \mathrm{V}
$$ 
Then
$$
\begin{split}
I_{E1} &=  \frac{3 - V_2}{9100} = \frac{3 - 0.9277227723}{9100} = 2.3 \cdot 10^{-4} \mathrm{A} \\
I_{B1} &= \frac{V_1}{100000} = \frac{0.2277227723}{100000} = 2.3 \cdot 10^{-6} \mathrm{A}\\
\\
I_{C1} &= I_{E1} – I_{B1}\\
    &= 2.3\cdot 10^{-4} – 2.3 \cdot 10^{-6}\\
    &= 2.254455446 \cdot 10^{-4} \mathrm{A}\\
\end{split}
$$
Now
$$
I_{C1} = \frac{V_3  + 3}{9100} + I_{B2}  
$$
thus
$$
\begin{split}
2.25 \cdot 10^{-4} &= \frac{V_3  + 3}{9100} + \frac{V_4  + 3}{4300}\\
2.25 \cdot 10^{-4} &= \frac{V_3  + 3}{9100} + \frac{V_3  - 0.7 + 3}{4300}\\
2.25 \cdot 10^{-4} &= \frac{V_3  + 3}{9100} + \frac{V_3  + 2.3}{4300}\\
2.25 \cdot 10^{-4} &= \frac{V_3  + 3}{9100} + \frac{V_3  + 2.3}{4300}\\
2.25 \cdot 10^{-4} &= \frac{4300V_3  + 12900}{39130000} + \frac{9100V_3  + 20930}{39130000}\\
2.25 \cdot 10^{-4} &= \frac{134V_3  +338.3}{391300}\\
88.21684159 &= 134V_3 + 338.3\\
-250.0831584 &= 134V_3\\
V_3 &= -1.866292227 \mathrm{V}\\ 
\end{split}
$$
and \$V_4 = V_3 – 0.7 = -1.866292227 – 0.7 = -2.566292227 \mathrm{V}\$. Then 
$$
\begin{split}
I_{E2} &= \frac{V_4  + 3}{4300} = \frac{-2.566292227+ 3}{4300} = 1.008622728 \cdot 10^{-4} \mathrm{A}\\
I_{C2} &= \alpha I_{E2} = 0.99(1.008622728 \cdot 10^{-4}) = 9.985365006 \cdot 10^{-5} \mathrm{A}\\
I_{B2} &= I_{E2} – I_{C2} = 1.008622728 \cdot 10^{-4} – 9.985365006 \cdot 10^{-5} = 1.008622737 \cdot 10^{-6} \mathrm{A}
\end{split}
$$
and 
$$
\begin{split}
I_{C2} &= \frac{3 - V_5}{5100}\\   
9.985365006 \cdot 10^{-5} &= \frac{3 - V_5}{5100} \\ 
0.5092536153 &= 3 – V_5\\
V_5 &= 2.490746385 \mathrm{V}
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Try simulating it.

Comment: I tried but it's off since the BJT isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\frac{V_4  + 3}{4300} is the equation for I_{E2}. Therefore, it needs to be multiplied by (1 – \alpha) to obtain I_{B2}.\
Thus 
$$
2.25 \cdot 10^{-4} &= \frac{V_3  + 3}{9100} + \frac{V_4  + 3}{4300}(1 – \alpha)\